# Using loop asked user to input numbers

Tags: c++

I have tried it with many different method but still doesn't work

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    float i=1,no,max=0,min=no;
    while(i>0){
        cout<<"Enter a number:";
        cin>>no; 
        if(no!=0) {                         
            if(no>max){
                max=no;
            }
            if(no<min){
                min=no;
            }
        }
        if(no==0){
            cout<<"max:"<<max<<endl;
            cout<<"min:"<<min<<endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: On line 4: `float min=no;` what is `no` at the time of this assignment?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly here:

```
float i = 1, no, max = 0, min = no;
```

`no` is uninitialized when you start using it. The behavior is undefined.

<s>Secondly, your `while` loop is an infinite loop since you never change the value of `i` or use `break`.</s>

Suggestions:

- Always initialize your built in types. Here you might need some different logic since you are trying to find a minimum and just initializing with `0` would not do, but I am not going to spoil your exercise
- <s>Make sure your loops are terminated at some point</s>
- Use `double` instead of `float`
- Properly indent your code

Comment: Note the `return 0;` in the `no==0` case. So, his loop will properly terminate once he enters `0`. At a first look, I missed that, too. @HMS as you see, even experienced programmers fail to read unstructured code. So, maybe that's the number one lesson you should learn from this :)

Comment: @sebrockm the indentation was just so very misleading and I missed the `return` part. Thank you for the the very much appreciated feedback!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout<< "Enter a number- Enter 0 to see result: ";
    int num = 0, max = 0, min=0;
    for( int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i){
        cin>> num;
        if(i==1){
            max=num;
            min=num;
        }
        else{
        if( num > max )
            max = num;
        else if( num == 0 )
            break;      
        else if( num < min )
              min = num;
    }

    }
    cout<<"min:"<< min <<"  max:"<< max;
    return 0;
}
```